# Is the strength level of my enemies fixed per location?

Tags: starfield

Let's assume my own level is currently 20. If I land on a new planet, is the strength level of my enemies (NPC, creatures) fixed?
Or is it based on my own level? Or even based on a combination of my own my companions level?

If I could visit the planet at the very beginning of the game would the enemies be weaker?
Or is the NPC X on planet Y always on level Z?

Comment: Systems generally show the level in the galaxy map